# print iframe content

Tags: printing, frame

I have an html page. The page content a frameset with 2 frame. 1 for menu and 1 for content.

```
<frameset border="4" cols="260, *">
    <frame id="menu" name="menu" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" src="Menu.html" onload="LoadPage();" >
    <frame id="Main" name="Main" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" src="" >
</frameset>
```

I want to force browser (mostly IE) to print the content of frame "Main" and not everything (menu and main)

tank you

Answer (score 1):

You can have this below code in your menu.html page or any other page which you are going to display in your iframe.

```
<a href="#" onClick="print(); return false;">Print Report</a>
```

Comment: what are the `</t>` tags? also you shouldn't wrap a block element (`<p>`) inside an inline element (`<a>`)

Comment: I don't think this achieves what the OP wants. If with the top window selected the user clicks the browser's print functionality, the whole lot will print. This is what the OP wants to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
         document.getElementById("ifrmeSummary").contentWindow.focus();
         document.getElementById("ifrmeSummary").contentWindow.print();
```

this will print only the iframe content and not the entitre screen/ window